# Data restructuring help: How to identify maximum number of days between 'events' and copy that value

Tags: r, variables, if-statement, dataframe

I cannot find a thread which answers this specific question, so help would be appreciated. 
I have a dataset that looks like this, where the variable 'EventCount' counts the number of days between events occurring for each person in the dataset (if EventCount=0, then event has occurred).

```
Day = c(1:8,1:8)
EventCount = c(NA,NA,0,1,2,0,1,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,0)
Person = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
dat <- data.frame(Person,Day,EventCount);dat
```

I am trying to restructure the dataset so that it takes the maximum value BETWEEN events occurring for each person, and copies or fills that value. I want it to look like this:

```
NewEvent = c(NA,NA,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,3,3,3,0,2,2,0)
dat2 <- dat <- data.frame(Person,Day,NewEvent);dat2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a bit complicated alteration I would write a function to modify the data frame. Something like this would work, but i'm sure there will be a 'Wow, that was easy' method.

```
fillDays <- function(df){
    df$NewEvent <- df$EventCount

    max <- 0
    updateFrom <- 1
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

        if(i %% 8 == 1){ # for each person
            max <- 0
        }
        val <- dat$EventCount[i]

        if(is.na(val)){ # If NA, no updates, just start from next record
            updateFrom =  updateFrom + 1 

        } else if(val == 0) { # If 0, set max to previous records

            if(updateFrom != i){
                df[updateFrom : (i-1), 'NewEvent'] <- max
            }
            max <- 0
            updateFrom = i + 1                

        } else { # update the max 
            if(val > max){
                max <- val
            }
        }
    }

    return(df)
}

> fillDays(dat)

#    Person Day EventCount NewEvent
# 1       1   1         NA       NA
# 2       1   2         NA       NA
# 3       1   3          0        0
# 4       1   4          1        2
# 5       1   5          2        2
# 6       1   6          0        0
# 7       1   7          1        1
# 8       1   8          0        0
# 9       2   1          0        0
# 10      2   2          1        3
# 11      2   3          2        3
# 12      2   4          3        3
# 13      2   5          0        0
# 14      2   6          1        2
# 15      2   7          2        2
# 16      2   8          0        0
```

For varying number of days,

```
fillDays <- function(df){
    df$NewEvent <- df$EventCount

    max <- 0
    updateFrom <- 1
    Person <- 1
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

        if(df$Person[i] != Person){
            max <- 0
            Person <- df$Person[i]
        }
        val <- dat$EventCount[i]

        if(is.na(val)){
            updateFrom =  updateFrom + 1

        } else if(val == 0) {

            if(updateFrom != i){
                df[updateFrom : (i-1), 'NewEvent'] <- max
            }
            max <- 0
            updateFrom = i + 1


        } else {
            if(val > max){
                max <- val
            }
        }
    }

    return(df)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this function does work for the example data I provided. In my actual dataset though, not every Person has 8 days, some might have more or less. I think this function only works if every Person has 8 days. Is there an easy way to amend the function so that it allows for this?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much - I've approved your answer!